# Scheduling thousands of tasks at almost the same time

Tags: python, scheduler

I have a network with several hosts. And then I have a traffic generator that schedules "flows" and tells the hosts to start them.

The traffic generator computes a list of flows that have to be scheduled with its initial time. So every time a flow has to be started in a host a function will be called and will tell the hosts that is listening for commands to start a flow.

So very simplified the scheduling would like that:

```
for flow in flows:
    self.scheduler.enter(flow["start_time"],1, self.startFlowSingle,[flow])
self.scheduler.run()

def startFlowSingle(self,flow):
    #sends command to the server
    clientName = self.topology.getHostName(flow["src"])
    self.unixClient.send(json.dumps({"type":"flow","data":flow.toDICT()}),clientName)
```

In the code above, `self.scheduler` its a `sched.scheduler` object and `self.unixClient` its used to send commands to the hosts.

However, if 100 hundred flows have to start at the exactly same time the scheduler will send all the commands sequentially and depending on the delay I guess this will make my flows to be delayed (and its something that I don't really want).

Is there a better or more efficient way to do that?

Comment: Schedule the flows on the clients not on the server.

Comment: For the moment they are all simulated in the same server. But doing so I will just avoid the IPC right? The rest would be the same. And I would need some kind of synchronisation so time t its the same in all the clients.

Comment: You are asking the right question, so I'm sure you will find a good solution. A full guidance through your project would be out of the scope of SO but if you have a new specific question, you can ask a new question here.

Comment: Okay thank you. And regarding the scheduler, is there something better than `sched` for what I want to do ?